# Is there a way to tell if my pet has grown up if it has a name?

Tags: nethack

Since my pet has a name, it will say the name of the pet in the messages window instead of its species. How can I still tell whether my pet has grown up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `FarLook` command (<kbd>;</kbd>) on your [pet](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Pet), or a [Stethoscope](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Stethoscope) or [Wand of Probing](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wand_of_probing). It will say <petname> the <species>.